# How can I group multi-word terms when creating a python wordcloud?

Tags: python, text, visualization

I am trying to create a wordcloud using python from a list of ingredients, some of which have more than one word in their name. I would like the wordcloud to consider those names as single elements, but I don't know how to achieve that. For example:

```py
import wordcloud as w
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ingredients = ['cabernet sauvignon', 'apple', 'black pepper',
             'rice', 'smoked salmon',
             'dried tomato', 'butter', 'mushroom', 'goat cheese']
frequencies = [55, 83, 33, 42, 19, 23, 5, 69, 1]

# Wordcloud asks for a string, and I have tried separating the terms with ',' and '~'

text = ''
for i, word in enumerate(ingredients):
    text = text + frequencies[i] * (word + ',') 

wordcloud = w.WordCloud(collocations = False).generate(text)

plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation = 'bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

The resulting wordcloud is the following. But, for example, I would like the term "cabernet sauvignon" to appear as only one word.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuHns.png

Comment: you want to use "generate_from_frequencies" if you already have the counts and terms extracted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `dict` in the form `{phrase: count, ...}` and use [`generate_from_frequencies`](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html#wordcloud.WordCloud.generate_from_frequencies):

```
d = dict(zip(ingredients, frequencies))
wordcloud = w.WordCloud(collocations=False).generate_from_frequencies(d)
```

Comment: Great Answer :) I think the collocations parameter is ignored in this case since the documentation for collocations says: "Ignored if using generate_from_frequencies."